# how to fetch data from server using graphql in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, graphql

> I am trying to fetch data from data from server . I tried to make
>   list and display on screen. but i didn't get any idea to proceed . In 
>   body , i also added  query of graphql.
>
> class Offers extends StatelessWidget {
>                @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>                   **final HttpLink httpLink =
>                       HttpLink(uri: 'link');
>
> ```
>             final AuthLink authLink = AuthLink(
>             getToken: () async => 'Bearer <token>',**
>             // OR
>             // getToken: () => 'Bearer 
>        <YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN>',   
>            );   final Link link = authLink.concat(httpLink as 
>            Link);
>             final ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client =
>                 ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient>(GraphQLClient(
>                     link: link,
>                     cache: InMemoryCache()));
>             return GraphQLProvider(
>               child: OfferList(),
>               client: client,
>             );   } }
>
>         class OfferList extends StatefulWidget {   @override   
>      _OfferListState createState() => _OfferListState(); }
>
>         class _OfferListState extends State<OfferList> {   
>        @override   
>        Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>             // TODO: implement build
>             return Scaffold(
>               appBar: AppBar(
>                 title: Text("Offers"),
>                 backgroundColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
>               ),
>                  body: Query(
>                   options: QueryOptions(document: """
>                 query(
>                   affOffers{
>                     edges {
>                       node {
>                         id  
>                         name  
>                         status  
>                         description  
>                         end_time  
>                         currency  
>                       }
>                     }
>                   }
>                   }
>                    """),
>                     builder: (
>                      QueryResult result, {
>                       VoidCallback refetch,
>                   }) {
>                     if (result.data == null) {
>                       return Text("No data found");
>                     }
>                     //return Text("Success");
>
>                     List offerLists = result.data['affOffers'] 
>   ['edges'] 
>                 ['node'];
>                     print(offerLists.length);
>                     return ListView.builder(
>
>                       itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int 
>              index) {
>                         final offer = offerLists[index];
>                         return Text(offer['name']);
>                       },
>                       itemCount: offerLists.length,
>                     );
>                   }),
>             );   
> }     }
> ```